# Website in ruby using Sinatra/Padrino

Tags: web, sinatra, padrino

i'm in engineering school and i'm very new in website development (not in my only did C language and algorithm) and i'd like to make one beautiful.
By searching, i read that using Padrino/Sinatra could be nice. I installed it, but i didn't find a tutorial which regroup all.
I'm so lost cause i find too much information but no good examples. In guides, i can't find anything on : how to design websites, how to make a menu...I think i really need examples or templates to start (a code to read).

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be in Ruby? You could just use a Wordpress/Joomla!/Drupal site. What do you need the site for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from here: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial

It cover most of important concept of padrino and sinatra.

The best way I suggest is to look a bit into opensource websites, for example ours: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-web

On github there are thousands of websites built with padrino or sinatra, so you can find more less/higher complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a bigger list:

https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/wiki/Projects-using-Padrino